# What is a dynamic RNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused about what dynamic RNN (i.e. `dynamic_rnn`) is. It returns an **output** and a **state** in TensorFlow. What are these state and output? What is dynamic in a dynamic RNN, in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 16):

Dynamic RNN's allow for variable sequence lengths. You might have an input shape `(batch_size, max_sequence_length)`, but this will allow you to run the RNN for the correct number of time steps on those sequences that are shorter than `max_sequence_length`.

In contrast, there are static RNNs, which expect to run the entire fixed RNN length. There are cases where you might prefer to do this, such as if you are padding your inputs to `max_sequence_length` anyway.

In short, `dynamic_rnn` is usually what you want for variable length sequential data. It has a `sequence_length` parameter, and it is your friend.

Comment: what is state and output? can you explain?

Comment: @xlax A pretty good explanation and example of the outputs can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239320/8236733

Comment: Looks like `sequence_length` is a vector specifying the length in each instance/batch. But ideally, the RNN should be able to infer the lengths from, well, the lengths (the input could be a list/array of variable-length lists/arrays), so you don't need to specify `sequence_length`. I think the keras LSTM handles this nicely, but I'm not sure about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn.

Answer (score 2):

While AlexDelPiero's answer was what I was googling for, the original question was different. You can take a look at this detailed description about LSTMs and intuition behind them. LSTM is the most common example of an RNN.

http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

The short answer is: the state is an internal detail that is passed from one timestep to another. The output is a tensor of outputs on each timestep. You usually need to pass all outputs to the next RNN layer or the last output for the last RNN layer. To get the last output you can use output[:,-1,:]

Comment: The first paragraph and the link fail to answer the question