# In Tensorflow, what is the difference between the returned 'output' and 'h' of state tuple (c, h) in LSTMCell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've searched across many tutorials/blogs/guides and official Tensorflow documentation to understand this. For example, see below lines:

```
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(512)
output, state_tuple = lstm(current_input, last_state_tuple)
```

Now if I unpack state,

```
last_cell_memory, last_hidden_state =  state_tuple
```

Both output and last_hidden_state have exact same dimensions of [batch_size, 512]. Can both be used interchangeably? I mean, can I do this? :

```
last_state_tuple= last_cell_memory, output
```

and then feed last_state_tuple in lstm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jacques's answer is correct, but it doesn't mention an important point: the state of LSTM layer *almost* always equals to the output. The difference becomes important when the chain of LSTM cells is long and not all input sequences have equal length (and hence are padded). That's when you should distinguish the state and output.

See the runnable example in [my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239320/712995) (it uses `BasicRNNCell`, but you'll get the same result with `LSTMCell`).

Comment: That's interesting, my implementation does use long, varying length sequences padded with zeros. This means one should always feed the last 'output' to get the output of current time-step and NOT the last 'h', as doing so will rather give you the output of time-step before which 'output' was == 'h'. This won't propagate the zero'd outputs till max sequence length, which is needed and the sole reason for padding sequences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second element of the state is the same as the output.

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMStateTuple

> Stores two elements: (c, h), in that order. Where c is the hidden state and h is the output.

Also to verify experimentally:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random as rng
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(10)
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 10))
stt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 10))
hdd = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 10))
out = lstm(inp, (stt, hdd))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
a = rng.randn(1, 10)
b = rng.randn(1, 10)
c = rng.randn(1, 10)
output = sess.run(out, {inp: a, stt: b, hdd: c})
assert (output[0] == output[1][1]).all()
```